# Crowdsourced average value

Tags: javascript, sql, text, average, mean

I am currently working on a "crowdsourced" average value calculator. The idea is to show a picture to people and ask them to guess the age of the person. Once they entered the value, I want to show them the average age the person was given.

Here is what I want to do exactly :

- Put a form online and ask people to put on a value
- Store the data entered
- Return the mean value people put there
- Calculate the standard deviation so that people cannot put a value too high or too low compared to what others put. That means the average value shown will be more accurate this way.

I am looking for the fastest way to do it, and here is what I thought about :

- Store the data in an SQL table and return the mean value through the AVG() function..but then, how would I calculate the Std. Dev ?
- Store the data in a txt file and use javascript to convert it to an array do the calculations.

But if I get like 20,000 different values, it might be slow to do either way. ?

I am quite a beginner in programming and what I propose might seem ridiculous...feel free to tell it to me !

Thank you all.

Comment: I believe 20.000 values is not yet a real concern, as long as you index the values correctly. To speed it up a bit you can demand integer values (opposed to float/double). Look at @Alex's answer for the `STDEV` function. And start worrying when you're calculating the standard deviation of, let's say, 1.000.000+ values

Comment: OT: It's a fun idea btw ;) you should try to connect this to facebook, can be a real runner!

Comment: Hello Giorgio, thanks a lot for your answer. Might be a good idea but I am not sure SQL is the best way if the app scales, is it ?

Comment: Why not? SQL is used for large enterprise applications as well. If the app scales, you should optimize your app. In example, don't calculate the standard deviation on each pageload, but once every 10 minutes. If you have such a large amount of records, the standard deviation won't change radically after each consecutive input anyway. And if you really have more then a million inputs this is merely a luxury problem. First try to hit the performance issue treshold.

Comment: True that. Thank you for your answer. I'll post the code on Stackoverflow as soon as it's functional :-)

Comment: One remark: do you realize that if you only allow users to input a value in the standard deviation range, the standard deviation will get smaller and smaller each time, until it's nearly zero and users can _only_ input the mean?If you want to restrict the range, you should at least take 2 times the standard deviation as a limit.

Comment: Hi Giorgio. It's true indeed. STDEV might not be the best solution. I could use the 25th percentile and the 75th then (but how in SQL?), or just calculate a value +-30% from the mean ?

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has [STDEV](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474(v=sql.105).aspx) (from 2005 onwards) so SQL sounds good for you.

> Returns the statistical standard deviation of all values in the
> specified expression. May be followed by the OVER clause.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> STDEV ( [ ALL | DISTINCT ] expression )
> ```
>
> **Arguments**
>
> ALL
>
> Applies the function to all values. ALL is the default.
>
> DISTINCT
>
> Specifies that each unique value is considered.
>
> expression
>
> Is a numeric expression. Aggregate functions and subqueries are not permitted. expression is an expression of the exact numeric or approximate numeric data type category, except for the bit data type.

Comment: Hello Alex, seems pretty cool, I didn't know about that one, thank you. What do you think the best way to proceed would be ? 

Call SQL STDEV when the page loads first to disable values above or below it, and then calculate the mean when the form is filled ?

Comment: I'd store the new data, then fetch the STDEV and return it to the page for display afterwards

Comment: Alex, thanks for your answer. The idea is to calculate the STDEV to make sure people put a value between the range. Is it possible to do it without reloading the page ?